# Categories & Variables

Tags: objective-c, categories

My question is quite simple.

In Objective C, what is the reason we cant have variables? If we ignore work arounds like Associative reference, extension, dynamic properties etc...what is the goal behind not allowing variables in Categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category provides an ability to add functionality to SDK class. First of all why we need categories we can extend a class to add functionality and data members to it.

Let say you want to extend some functionality of UINavigationController you can subclass and add whatever your requirement. But UINavigationController is also part of some SDK controls e.g. UIImagePickerController and more tab in UITabBarController. What you gonna  do to that Navigation Controller you don’t have access to it.

See my blog post for details http://muhammadzahidimran.com/2016/12/09/adding-data-to-sdk-classes-using-categories/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add variables to an existing class, use **Subclassing**.

If you want to simple add your own methods to existing classes, use **Categories**.

> Categories can be used to declare either instance methods or class
>   methods but are not usually suitable for declaring additional
>   properties. It’s valid syntax to include a property declaration in a
>   category interface, but it’s not possible to declare an additional
>   instance variable in a category. This means the compiler won’t
>   synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property
>   accessor methods. You can write your own accessor methods in the
>   category implementation, but you won’t be able to keep track of a
>   value for that property unless it’s already stored by the original
>   class.
>
> The only way to add a tradition property—backed by a new instance
>   variable—to an existing class is to use a class extension, as
>   described in “[Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)”

**What is the goal behind not allowing variables in Categories?**

Methods within a **Category** are added to a class at **run-time**, this means the compiler won’t synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property accessor methods.

On the other hand when using subclassing, the class is compiled at the same time as the class extension.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you mentioned makes perfect sense. But my query is was there any constraint which rendered adding instance variables in category while designing categories. Categories are widely considered to be an alternative to subclassing. So why not add a feature which would make it closer to subclassing in addition to the benefits. I believe its more of a design decision rather than constraints of any sort. This is what I wanted to confirm. Thanks

Comment: Okay. Yah. That makes sense.